# Parsing a query string with the qs library not parsing nested objects correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am sending a query string to a node express server using the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library. The server parse results are not what I expected. The nested `$regex` is not parsed properly. Are there options I need to provide to get the desired result?

```
const query = {location: { $regex: '^F', $options: 'i' }};
const queryString = qs.stringify(query, { encode: false });
```

stringifed query sent to server: "location[$regex]=^F&location[$options]=i"

```
const query =  qs.parse(queryString);
```

parsed query result: {"location":{"$regex":"^Flocation[$options]=i"}}

expected query result: {"location": { "$regex": "^F", "$options": "i" }}

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the query string sent. It was sent as an array by mistake while I was fixing that issue on the server side with Object.values() it wasn't keeping the "&" char. Fixing that issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218564/angular-7-x-query-to-node-express-server-is-converted-to-an-object-array-of-char) solved this one.