# Angular 7.x query to node express server is converted to an object array of characters

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I am sending a query string to a node express server. When I access the req.query property it is an array of characters instead of a normal object or the string I sent. Any Ideas?

Query sent

```
const data = await this.cspCrudService.findOne(stringQuery);
```

service

```
findAll(params: any): Promise<T[]> {
 THIS LINE BELOW WAS THE PROBLEM
 const query = StringUtil.toMongoQueryString(params);
 return this.httpClient.get<T[]>(`${this.url}${this.endpoint}/${query}`).toPromise();
}
```

"location[$regex]=^F&location[$options]=i"

```
req.query
```

```
{"0":"l","1":"o","2":"c","3":"a","4":"t","5":"i","6":"o","7":"n","8":"[","9":"$","10":"r","11":"e","12":"g","13":"e","14":"x","15":"]","16":"=","17":"^","18":"F","19":"","20":"l","21":"o","22":"c","23":"a","24":"t","25":"i","26":"o","27":"n","28":"[","29":"$","30":"o","31":"p","32":"t","33":"i","34":"o","35":"n","36":"s","37":"]","38":"=","39":"i"}
```

Comment: How you send it? Insert the code of Http request.

Comment: @MaihanNijat After you requested the code I noticed the problem. I added "StringUtil.toMongoQueryString" function some time ago and forgot it was there. After removing it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added a "StringUtil.toMongoQueryString" function some time ago for testing and forgot it was there. After removing it all worked as expected.